# In select2 suggestion list highligting of typed character is not showing

Tags: jquery-select2, highlighting

I am trying to migrate from select2 version 2 to version 4. Highlighting of typed characters in the suggestion list was happening properly in the old version; but now its not happening. This was the code I used for highlighting:

```
.select2-result-selectable .select2-match, .select2-result-unselectable     .select2-match
{
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in version 4+, you need to handle the templateResult. Basically, you need to get the term and replace the result with your own template.

I made a sample for you that replaces the result to another with the term in bold. However you can customize the result (with colors etc) as you need. PS: The term is getted using jquery, but you could replace it for javascript if  you need.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectStates').select2({
    templateResult: formatSingleResult
  });
});

function formatSingleResult(result) {
    var term =$(".selectStates").data("select2").dropdown.$search.val();
    var reg = new RegExp(term, 'gi');
    var optionText = result.text;
    var boldTermText = optionText.replace(reg, function(optionText) {return `<b>${optionText}</b>`});
    var $item = $(`<span> ${boldTermText}  </span>`);
    return $item;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select class="selectStates">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

Here is the working sample: https://codepen.io/cassioseffrin/pen/pLYyVv

Comment: Doesn't work for `+` symbol. When I type `+` in search-box, it throws error in console `Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat `. Is there a work-around for searching the `+` symbol? Thanks in advance

Comment: @noviceinDotNet. I am sure you could fix it editing the regex expression (new RegExp(term, 'gi')). Line 10 of JS file

Answer (score 0):

You can also place code to processResults function

```
$('.selectStates').select2({
    // ...
    processResults: function (data, params) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data.items, function(obj) {
                        var term = params.term;
                        var reg = new RegExp(term, 'gi');
                        var optionText = obj.text;
                        var boldTermText = optionText.replace(reg, function(optionText) { return "<b>" + optionText + "</b>" });
                        var text = "<span>" + boldTermText + "</span>";

                        return { id: obj.id, text: text };
                    })
                };
            },
     escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; },
     //...
});
```